# Why the main pencilblue module does not have the pencilblue.js

Tags: javascript, pencilblue

Normally for plugins in pencilblue when the file `details.json`  refers the main module like this:

`"main_module": {
        "path": "pencilblue.js"
    },`

I am expecting to see the file `pencilblue.js` in the same directory as the file  `details.json`.

But for the pencilblue plugin which is supposed to be a plugin like the others the file `pencilblue.js` is not present in the same directory . For all other plugins when the `main_module` refers a file I can find it in the same directory.

What did i miss and how this one is different ?

thanks for your support.

The github repo for pencilblue just in case: https://github.com/pencilblue/pencilblue
the plugin directory is right there.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, while the answer is certainly not intuitive, I believe it makes some sense: `pencilblue` is the core plugin which is required to make everything work. Unlike other plugins, the core PencilBlue plugin references at a root level. The file `details.json` is looking for in this case is the `pencilblue.js` on the root level of the repo. I am not certain about the underlying reason for building the plugin in this manner, but knowing the application is non-functional makes the root-level reference a bit less of mystery.